# How to repair broken suspended cement slab

Tags: concrete, foundation, slab, cement, footings

The very corner of the cement slab, which forms the floor of my basement, broke off.  There was nothing supporting it underneath.  the portion that broke off forms a triangle 11" x 10" x 14" x 3-6" thick.  The chunk was bordering the concrete footings.  The dirt in the hole is soft and loose.  At least 6 sqft at that corner of the slab is suspended without support.  I'm including a couple photos up underneath the slab.  I suspect that there is erosion or settlement caused by water.  What would be the easiest way to prevent further damage to the structure for as long as possible?  My idea is to dig out as much dirt as possible and then pack the hole with rocks.  At what point would excavating the loose soil undermine the support of the footings and slab?  Thanks for any ideas or insights you are able to provide.

Here is video for context:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flipt-temporary-storage/foundation_hole.mp4

[image]
[image: photo underneath slab]
[image: photo underneath]

Comment: The slab is supposed to rest on the footings. Any idea why it isn't? I can't get much context from the photos. Anyway, you'll want to determine whether settling is still occurring, then fill with sand or gravel. Water could help compact it before repairing the slab. "Rocks" are not compactible.

Comment: Thank you @isherwood.  The slab does not seem to make contact with the footings at all.  As far as I can tell, it is floating on the dirt.  I might point out that I discovered this problem while filling the gap between the slab and footings with Sikaflex.  The house is part of a makeshift settlement built during WWI to support the logging industry.  It was probably constructed in whatever way was expedient.

By "repairing the slab" do you mean pouring new cement on top of the recommended sand/gravel.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: here is a video which may give more context:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flipt-temporary-storage/foundation_hole.mp4

Comment: Yes, that's the repair I meant. Please edit new information into your question body.

Comment: My plan is to 1) fill the hole with gravel and sand, leveling it with the bottom of the slab 2) pour water into the hole and then let it dry 3) fill the hole with cement, leveling it with the top of the slab.  I have 2 more questions at this point: Would it be advisable to dig out the loose dirt before adding gravel?  and should I put some kind of spacer between the new cement and the footings seeing as how there is a gap between the slab and footings everywhere else?  Thanks a bunch for all your help.

Comment: You're not going to gain much by removing the dirt since the rest of the slab is sitting on it. Obviously, you can remove the loosest stuff if it comes out easily. Alternatively, ram it down with a length of stout timber. I've never seen anyone pour concrete directly on soil, not even outside on a driveway! I assume it's not a part of your living accomodation?

Comment: @handyman Thanks for your input.  Now you have me alarmed.  Yes, this cement slab forms the floor of a finished section of the house.  Before I purchased the house, it was a bedroom.  There was a composite floating-floor on top of the cement which I recently removed.  Based on what I see (and have depicted in the photos) There is just this floating slab of cement  between the living space of the home and the earth.  Perhaps I should investigate further.  Any advice is most welcome.

Comment: There is a hole in the concrete wall about 1 inch in diameter.  It appears in the topmost pic.  It exits the foundation at ground level.  The slab has gutters running along the edges which converge at the damaged corner.  The corner was a kind of depressed basin.  I believe it was intended to funnel water out through the hole.  I'm wondering if i should repair this system, or if I should install a more proper drain with a pipe exiting the wall, or if I should plug the hole and repair the slab level.  The present damage seems to have been caused by water under the slab not on top of it.

Comment: Trying to picture how a basement floor slab can be at ground level? In what country are you located also? (just that most countries require some sort of damp proof membrane... If it was mine, I'd have it all out, stone/hardcore in, compact, rigid insulation in and then a membrane and concrete to finish. But basements are often complicated as you have found. Water ingress is difficult to manage.

Comment: I am in the U.S.  Everett WA.  The house is on a hill.  On the East, the slab is about 4' below ground.  On the west it is about 6" above ground.  The hole is at the SW corner.  I will consider removing and replacing the slab.  For now, my intention is to leave the hole open through a few wet days to see if I can detect any moisture that might be causing settlement and then base a further decision on that info.  I really appreciate everyone's help.  This has been very valuable.

Comment: Might be worth factoring in that it 'should' be very easy to break out. Once there is a void underneath concrete it will be in tension (weaker) and it breaks up quite easily using a sledgehammer, working away from the hole. In essence, getting a hole started is half the battle, so you have a good head start.